# Javascript create Object by array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I try to create an object with a value for the last key. I just have an Array with the keys and the value but dont know how it will be possible to create an object without use references in javascript.

As far as I know there isnt a way to create a reference of a variable in javascript.

This is what i have:

```
var value = 'test';
var keys = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'];
```

This is what i want:

```
myObject: {
   this : {
     is: {
       a : {
         test : 'test'
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Any idea how i can do this the best way in JavaScript ?

Comment: [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)?

Comment: I dont think that JSON can help me with this. I have an Array with Keys. Every key have to be a new object in the object. And the last key has the value of the variable "value".

Comment: Are you sure that inner value isn't meant to be `test: 'Test'`?

Comment: @Phil yes - for sure. My fault. I will edit the question. But thanks to your awesome answer (: It still works how it has to work.

Comment: I edited to a salomonic data, so no previously correct answer gets incorrect :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this...

```js
const value = 'test'
const keys = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']

const myObject = keys.reduceRight((p, c) => ({ [c]: p }), value)

console.info(myObject)
```

Or, if you're not a fan of object literal key shortcuts and arrow functions...

```
keys.reduceRight(function(p, c) {
  var o = {};
  o[c] = p;
  return o;
}, value);
```

See [Array.prototype.reduceRight() - Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight#Polyfill) if you need IE <= 8 support.

Comment: It has an error in the final node, but this code is so beautiful I can't downvote it

Comment: It finally creates `test: "Test"` instead of `Test : "test"`. But anyway, altough it's not correct it has my vote, nice code

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado Ah. The OP's description makes it sound like the `value` should be the inner-most value, not key. I've asked for clarification

Comment: Wow. Awesome. Never heard about this method in javascript before. Thanks for this clean code. I will try it and will work with this. Edit: I tried it and this works fine for my issue! Many thanks dude :)

Answer (score 4):

With this:

```
var curObj = myObject = {};
for(var i=0; i<keys.length-1; i++)
   curObj = curObj[keys[i]] = {};    
curObj[value] = keys[i];
```

Outputs:

```
{
   this : {
     is: {
       a : {
         Test : 'test'
       }
     }
   }
}
```

As opposed to the other answers, this outputs *exactly* what you asked for.

Cheers

Comment: Did you get that terseness from my answer, or on your own? (s'ok either way)

Comment: I was refactoring each minute (you can see the editions), didn't even realize you answered. Mine gives a different result, though

Comment: Yes, yours gives the answer the OP asks for (which I suspect is wrong :)

Comment: Anyhow, note that the value of `i` after the loop will be the value of `keys.length-1`, so you can use that to make your last line cleaner, if you like.

Comment: Don't look now but OP updated their question ;). Still gets my upvote for the effort of figuring out how to solve the more difficult original query

Comment: Thanks Phil, that was an unlogical challenge xD

Answer (score 2):

```
var o={}, c=o;
var value = 'Test';
var keys = 'this is a test'.split(' ');

for (var i=0; i<keys.length-1; ++i) c = c[keys[i]] = {};
c[keys[i]] = value;

console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
// {"this":{"is":{"a":{"test":"Test"}}}}
```

Comment: `keys` was already an array? Why turn it into a string then back to an array?

Comment: @Phil BC I was too lazy to use the mouse to copy/paste, and I wanted to show the OP an alternate lazy-programmer way to create an array of strings with less typing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output like

```
{
   this : {
     is: {
       a : 'test'
     }
   }
}
```

Do the following

```
var keys = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'];
var output = keys.reduceRight((p,c)=>({[c]:p}))
console.log(output)
```

And the output will be like

```
{ this: { is: { a: 'test' } } }
```