# Object: Do not delete existing keys

Tags: javascript, object

Hi have the following code snipped. ([Javascript create Object by array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987547/javascript-create-object-by-array/20987675#20987675)
The problem is, this will delete my existing key, but i want to keep and update them. Only if the key not exists, then should add it.

```js
function setValueToLightGroup(Group, keys, value) {  
  let c=Group;
  keys = keys.split('.'); 

  for (var i=0; i<keys.length-1; ++i) c = c[keys[i]] = {};
  c[keys[i]] = value;  
}

setValueToLightGroup(LightGroups[`FlurEG`], 'autoOff.timers.startTimer', 300);
setValueToLightGroup(LightGroups[`FlurEG`], 'autoOff.enabled', true); 
setValueToLightGroup(LightGroups[`FlurEG`], 'power', true);
```

Comment: Does `c[keys[i]] ??= {}` instead of `c[keys[i]] = {}` work?

Comment: You could also use the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator ..

Comment: @adiga yes, that should work. The problem is the `for` loop body. There, you just overwrite the contents of each key with `{}`. You have to check first whether the object already has a value for that key or not before you overwrite.

Comment: @derpirscher since they have `var i`, it will be available through out the function, even after `for` is done. It's a bit of a hack which can cause confusion.

Comment: @adiga yes, `c[keys[i]] ??= {}`  works, but getting a syntax error on "??=". Should I ignore it? _Expected an identifier and instead saw '?'._  // _Expected an operator ans instead saw '='_

Comment: @derpirscher `const` and `let` doesn't work

Comment: @MarkusHartmann No you should not ignore syntax errors ... In what environment are you running this code? The [`==?` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) is supported in recent versions of most browsers and in nodejs it's supported since version 15.0.

Comment: @derpirscher I tested it simple on jsfiddle. But usually I’m working on nodejs v14.

Answer (score 0):

The general problem is that you overwrite the previous value of `c[keys[i]]` in every iteration of the `for` loop with `{}`. If you want to keep the previous contents, please only overwrite the contents if the key does not exist.

```
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
  if (!(keys[i] in c)) { // <-- this check avoids that value is overwritten
    c[keys[i]] = {};
  }
  c = c[keys[i]];
}
```

As noted in the comments, an alternative would be using [`??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) for the assignment. It performs the assignment if the left hand side is undefined.